# How to click submit bouton validate or autoclick and made url

Tags: html, validation, jscript, confirm

I need a solution or html code or jscript to modify my url for my visitors for example if you want to visit my blog on the skyblog site result is blocked by skyblog so to acces my blog visiters must submit button then validate how to avoid and trensform url directly from my skyblog to my blog two link with modification of html or url or to add script to url ex my url:

```
http://www.skyrock.com/r?url=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.blogspot.com%2F
```

[button confirm validate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6eyZE.jpg)

Html code:

```
<a class="bouton confirm validate" href="http://example.blogspot.com">Continue</a>
```

[button confirm validate code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mig9D.jpg)

So I need help to this tricks. I am sure there is an html code, a script or a web site to change url from script to url, or from html code to link.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not quite sure if this is what you want but, if you want to change your href with a script on your confirm btn link u can use this Jquery code,  `$(".confirm ").attr("href", "http://www.google.com/")`. This will change your link to google when its fired.I'm not sure where do you want to fire this change tho

Comment: this code is uses for your own page but my question is to change the direction of visiters to my page directly without click on submit button i can build a url link how do this job?ex http://www.skyrock.com/r?url=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.blogspot.com%2F  this is a original link but he take me to submit button so i need to pass directly to my page i c'ant modifiate a page source of skyrock  have you understand me this link + html code or jscript to pass the submit button =new link to my page other QU is it possible to turn a code html or js to a link like this form www.example.com thanks brother

Comment: any one have this trick please

Comment: Oh okey, I see your problem. So, what do you have access to? I mean what can you change because without access you cant do anything really and if you do its most probably illegal. however, can you tell me how do you get to the validation page?what i really want to know is : how do you get to [this](http://www.skyrock.com/r?url=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.blogspot.com%2F) page? is it a link from your blog or someone else blog?

Comment: i had a quick look at skyrock blogs and i dont think you can do much about it

Comment: no its not my blog it is just an example I gave that name at random there is a probleme ?

Comment: so amin it is impossible or difficult there is a solution ! i think i heard some were that its possible but i d'ont know

Comment: Here's what i understand : someone linked your blog(lets say your blog is example.blogspot.com) inside a "skyrock blog" and when people click on the link they receive this redirect notice. if that's the case,to best of my knowledge, i don't think you can avoid the notice.